# How to download a file with Python using tqdm

Tags: python

I want to make a .py file that downloads an image from a link with a progressbar included can I do it with tdqm?

This is what I have so far

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

chunk_size = 1024

url = "example.com"

r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

total_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
filename = url.split('/')[-1]

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for data in tqdm(iterable = r.iter_content(chunk_size = chunk_size)):         
        total = total_size/chunk_size, unit = 'KB')
        f.write(data)
print("Download complete!")
```

Comment: And what was the problem you encountered?

Comment: You've done a great job! so which part exactly made you not go further?

Comment: The thing is how do I implement a file into the code and it shows the download progress bar at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
import math
url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

total_size = int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0))
block_size = 1024
wrote = 0 
with open('output.bin', 'wb') as f:
    for data in tqdm(r.iter_content(block_size):
        total=math.ceil(total_size//block_size) , unit='KB', unit_scale=True)
        wrote = wrote  + len(data)
        f.write(data)
if total_size != 0 and wrote != total_size:
    print("ERROR, something went wrong")
```